# Linearization of autonomous DE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been working through this [PDF about DEs](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-i-first-order-differential-equations/linear-vs.-nonlinear/MIT18_03SCF11_s11_1text.pdf).

There was the logistic equation $$\dot{y}=k_0y(1-y/p),$$ where $k_0$ and $p$ are constants. Then a new variable is introduced $y=u+p$.  Then $$1-\frac{y}{p}=-\frac{u}{p}.$$ After substituting in the first equation, according to the PDF this should yield $$\dot{u}=-k_0\frac{u}{p}(p-u).$$ I think this is wrong. It should be $$\dot{u}=-k_0\frac{u}{p}(p+u).$$ Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right as far as I can tell. Since, the higher order terms are ignored he did not take the time to check the calculation fully as in both cases it yields the same linearised form.

However..using $y = p - u$
$$
\dot{y} = k_0y\left(1-\frac{y}{p}\right)
$$
The sub
$$
\frac{y}{p} = -\frac{u}{p} + 1
$$
thus
$$
\dot{u} = -k_0\left(-u+p\right)\frac{u}{p} = -k_0\frac{u}{p}(p-u)
$$
But in either case there is an error.